# How do I use the Phanteks fan hub with Corsair H110i GTX

Tags: pc, windows, case, fan-controller

I recently built a new computer, and I'm having some issues (I think).

Here's my gear

Case: [Phanteks Enthoo Evolv ATX](http://www.phanteks.com/Enthoo-Evolv-ATX.html)

Case Accessory: [Phanteks fan hub](http://i.gyazo.com/b2d3f2f75cf48491cfcd5ccbc64aa8db.png)

Mobo: [Asus Maximus VIII Hero](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/MAXIMUS-VIII-HERO/)

CPU Cooler: [Corsair Hydro Series H110i GTX](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/hydro-series-h110i-gtx-280mm-extreme-performance-liquid-cpu-cooler)

My issue is that the instructions that come with the Phanteks case is pretty lacking on instructions for the fan hub on the back.  I've read conflicting information on how to connect these devices, and I figured I'd ask here to make sure I actually did it correctly.

My problem is that right now, the fans all stay 100% all the time.  It's pretty loud, and it's possible that that's the way it's supposed to be, but I hope not.  To be clear, the case fans appear to be the culprits.

Here's how I have everything set up:

`H110i GTX
        | 
        |two fan cables
        ------------------------>both fans
        |
        |water pump
        ------------------------>CPU_FAN
        |
        |data cable
        ------------------------>USB 2.0`

`Phanteks fan hub
        | 
        |CPU_FAN
        ------------------------>CPU_OPT
        |
        |Sata power
        ------------------------>Sata power
        |
        |3 x 4 pin fans
        ------------------------>3 Case fans`

The real confusion here is caused by the fact that the Phanteks case instructions say to connect their fan hub to the cpu_fan, but so does the H110i.  From googling around, I found some people that had done it this way, but man, this thing is loud.  Any advice?

---

**EDIT 1**

Another thing I should mention.  I'm using the AI Suite 3 software that came with the mobo.  It's supposed to let you control the case fan speeds.  When I have the fan hub connected to CPU_OPT, it's  not showing any case fans in the software.  If I connect CPU_OPT to any other fan connection on the mobo, then it shows up, but it still won't let me change any values.

---

**EDIT 2**

After a little more research, I found out that the AI Suite 3 software won't have any control over your fans if you don't set the fan mode to PWM in the bios.  I went into the bios, and now it controls the fans.  The only issue now is that the case fans aren't turning on at all.  I'm wondering if the temperature just isn't high enough, and they'll turn on once it's higher.  If it turns on when the heat is higher, or if it doesn't turn on, I'll report back here.

Comment: I've closed this question because it's asking us for technical support. Remember that we can't do troubleshooting, tech support or compatibility queries. If your question isn't any of those, please clarify exactly what hardware you're looking for, and make sure your question focuses on the hardware recommendation rather than the tech support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why I didn't find this solution a little faster, I guess I was just googling the wrong thing.  The phantek hub needs to be plugged into a fan connection on the mobo, but not the CPU_OPT.

Then, in the bios, you need to allow your fans to be controlled by something other than the bios.

After that, everything worked fine.